# play flv file in videoview in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell how to play flv file in video view in android give example

Thanks

Comment: There is a workaround which will also allow you to play from a local asset resource, please read my answer to this similar question for a full solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't.  The stock version of Android doesn't come with a parser capable of parsing whatever proprietary standard that Adobe has.  However, there is a good chance that vendors have added their own parsers, but that chances that FLV is one of them is extremely low.  Even if you did find a vendor who has included, you're pretty much guaranteed that your app won't behave the same on every phone.